# Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception when loading views inside view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am loading a header and footer in each page without using blade and just using `echo View:make('templates/header');` and at the end of the page likewise with the footer.

I am loading these same header and footer views in exactly the same manner in other views without problems, but when I call this particular view from my controller, I get this very non-informational Laravel error message. It's very basic HTML right now as I'm still in the building/testing phase. I don't know why loading the header and footer views in other views I'm using works, but here they're crashing.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
echo View::make('templates/header');
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Record Saved!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<?
echo View::make('templates/footer');
```

Is there any way to get more information out of Laravel to find out what it's not liking?

Comment: what kind of *non-informational* laravel error message?

Comment: Well what exactly it's trying to convert to a string would be a good start.

Just saying that it's _to_string() function must not throw an exception doesn't give me much to work with.

Answer (score 1):

__toString() calls the render() method on `View` ([source](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.View.html#___toString)). the exception is therefore thrown within **templates.footer** or **templates.header**.

Comment: I suppose I didn't make that part obvious in my OP, but no kidding? LOL

Comment: yeah, and you didn't post any code from those views. so you have got it narrowed down, where to look for your error.

Comment: What I really wanted to know was if there is a way to tell Laravel to be more verbose about what it's not liking. Simply saying that one of their functions must not throw an error without giving some indication as to what exactly it's erroring on isn't very useful.

Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: ah i see. you got a some error logging going on in **app/storage/logs/laravel.log**.

Answer (score 0):

In blade template file, You do not need to write `<?php ?>` Tag.

also use `include` instead of `View::make` in blade file.

```
@include('templates.header');
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Record Saved!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
@include('templates.footer');
```

**Note**: [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) file must has extension `.blade.php`

Hope it will help you :-)